# Как использовать React, RequireJS и Babel для трансформации JSX в браузере?

Tags: javascript, requirejs, babel, reactjs

Во время разработки хочется подключать JSX файлы, их редактировать и перегрузив страницу, видеть изменения. Не выполняя каждый раз компиляцию JSX в JS.

Помогите разобраться, как подключить JSX файл и Babel через RequireJS?

Впервые ставлю Babel, и запутался с путями. Покажите работающий пример конфига RequireJS?

Comment: не очень понял зачем вам requirejs если бабель умеет в commonjs компилить. https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/modules/

Comment: на стадии разработки я не хочу ничего копмилировать иначе, чем на лету в браузере.

Comment: не знаю, watch удобнее в любом случае, неужели у вас настолько долгая компиляция jsx ? ещё трансформер удобно ставить на уровне вебсервера иногда

Comment: как в react-express generator